# Media query being executed after it should

Tags: html, css, media-queries, flexbox

I am working with `flex` items so I think it could be the problem of why my code is making a strange behaviour.

I have `.flexContainer` class that has a `max-width` property. After I resize the window, I want to change this `max-width` property to a higher value but if I set my media query as:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 850px){
    .flexContainer{
       max-width: 60%; 
    }
}
```

the `max-width` of the element is changing at `835px` instead of `850px`.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left" class="block">Left</div>
  <div id="center" class="block">
    <div class="flexContainer">
      <div class="flexDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexContainer">
      <div class="flexDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexContainer">
      <div class="flexDiv"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="block">Right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.block{
    flex: 1;
}

#left{
    background-color: green;
}

#center{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
    align-content: flex-start;
}

#right{
    background-color: orange;
}

.flexContainer{
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
}

.flexDiv{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px){
    .flexContainer{
       max-width: 60%; 
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5h9rjcd/2/) in which you can see that the `max-width` property changes at `835px` instead of `850px`.

**EDIT:** I add two screenshots so you can see it:

[image]

[image]

Why the media query is being executed after it should?

Comment: It's changing to max-width: 60%; right at 850px for the iframe on the fiddle

Comment: @Chizzle In my case it is changing at `835px`. Also I am getting the same issue on my real project so I tried to simplify it here on a JSFiddle.

Comment: Try putting `!important` to the max-width: 850px

Comment: It's functioning as I would expect it to, as Chizzle mentioned, It's changing right at 850px in my browser/OS on that fiddle (Chrome 52.0.2723.2 dev (64-bit) on Mac OS X) -- what's your browser?

Comment: @ArthurWeborg It is Google Chrome but I do not know how to see which version of it. I will add two screenshots so you can see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for posting the screenshots. Based on your screenshots, it appears you are hovering over the `body` tag, not the `iframe`. if you hover over the iframe, you'll see it's at 850 px width that it changes. Also, if you click the hamburger icon in the upper right corner of chrome, go down to help, there will be an option for about google chrome, you can find the version in there for future reference :)

Comment: @ArthurWeborg Yes, I notice it and put in an answer as fast I saw the problem. I wanted to reproduce the problem of my real project and simplify it here (to be more clear and not to paste lines and lines of html and css) but it seems I simplified too much. I will try to search it and edit the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem here. Just I had to remove the `margin` of the `body` tag.

I will try to reproduce the effect that I am having on my real project (in which I have `body` tag fixed) and edit the question again.

**EDIT:** It seems that it was a bug or something similar of `Google Chrome` because I cannot reproduce the error anymore.

The error that I was getting is that when I looked at `html` tag on my `Google Chrome` inspector, it gave to me the wrong values for the webpage (around 30px less, and I do not have any `padding/margin` around it) so I thought that the media queries were being executed in the wrong `width` of the screen.

I know this is a "stupid" solution but it worked again when I closed and re-opened `Google Chrome`. Now it works like normal behaviour.